# Given a long which comprises of multiplying prime numbers together as key, How to determine hashTable size?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

Basically the goal is to find pairs of permutations in a txt file provided.

What I've done was to create a byte[] from the given file, transposed the elements from the byte[] into primenumbers using a static array of asciiToPrimeNumbers (ascii will be the index of this array and it's corresponding value is the i-th prime number) used a HashMap as a lookup table.

Since the multiplication of prime numbers guarantees a unique key (in the case of permutations they'll generate the same key) i'll replace/put the value into my hashmap.

The issue is this is not as fast as i want it to be. So what i'm trying to do now is to create my own array to store the recurrences instead of using java's hashmap as it's rather slow. The issue is i dont know how to determine the size of said array from the getgo.

```
static int[] asciiToPrime = new int[] {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67,
        71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181,
        191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311,
        313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443,
        449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593,
        599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719};

public int processData(String filename){
    try {
        byte[] xs = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(filename));
        int pairs = 0;
        HashMap<Long, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<>();
        long keyToPut = 1;
        for (int i = 5; i < xs.length; i++) {
            if (xs[i] != 10) {
                keyToPut *= asciiToPrime[xs[i]];
            } else {
                if (hmap.get(keyToPut) != null) {
                    int value = hmap.get(keyToPut);
                    pairs += value;
                    hmap.replace(keyToPut, value + 1);
                } else {
                    hmap.put(keyToPut, 1);
                }
                keyToPut = 1;
            }
        }
        return pairs;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: *instead of using java's hashmap as it's rather slow* That is a **false** premise. Post your code.

Comment: it's posted and im trying to get away from using generics. IIRC processing primitives is significantly faster

Comment: If I'm reading your code correctly, your maximum key is `719^(length of longest string)`, which will easily overflow an integer, and could overflow a `long`. So the size of your array would have to be 2^64. You'd be better off creating strings from those byte values, and then using a standard hash map with the built-in hashing function.